# Bombardment verbs in English

Tags: verbs

Which one of the sentences bellow sound unidiomatic to the (especially American English) natives:

> - They **bombed** the homes of defenseless people on a daily basis.
> - They **threw the bombs** on the homes of defenseless people on a daily basis.
> - They **bombarded** the homes of defenseless people on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best of the three is:

> They **bombed** the homes of defenseless people on a daily basis.

[Bombard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bombard) already includes the concept of "constantly or repeatedly" so your "on a daily basis" becomes redundant and that phrase is better because it's more specific.

**Bombed** is better than **threw the bombs** because it focuses on the effect more than the action, and it is clear from context (esp. inclusion of the word 'defenseless') that you wish to emphasize the effects on the people who were bombed.  **Threw the bombs** would be better if you were writing about repetitive-motion shoulder injuries, which would seem callous in context (like Nazi soldiers' complaints about clothing torn in [Kristallnacht raids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kristallnacht)).
**Bombed** is more visual and direct. The reader will understand the intended communication most easily with **bombed**.

None of the three are idioms.

Answer (score 1):

The middle one is unidiomatic.

> They **threw the bombs** on the homes of defenseless people on a daily basis.

You don't **throw the bombs**, you **drop the bombs**.

The third one is technically correct, but sounds strange to me. This is because you've got redundancy in that sentence.

The definition for bombard (as you use it) is:

> to attack (a place or person) continuously with bombs, shells, or other missiles.

To bombard something implies a constant barrage of attacks. However, you put at the end of your sentence "on a daily basis." That is why it sounds a bit strange to my ear. It makes it sound as if they are being bombed almost all day, every single day. It is a stronger phrasing than the other two, and implies heavier attacking.

Comment: [Bombs can be thrown too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_grenade), not just dropped.

Comment: @WBT in that case, you'd be throwing a hand grenade, not a bomb. Yes, a hand grenade is technically not a bomb, but I don't think people equate the two in speech. A bomb brings to mind an image of, well, a bomb.

Comment: @WBT you would also throw a hand grenade into the homes, not on the homes

Comment: I've seen lots of bomb-throwing on TV and in the movies, including sticks of dynamite with burning fuses, etc. which strike me as unrealistic (excuses for pyrotechnic-loving action film directors?) but I don't know much about bomb-throwing myself.  Bombs can also be rocket-launched. OP's question might be about bombs in the Israeli-Palestinian conflict, for example.